# Can the 25th bit of arm7tdmi Data-processing instructions be 0?

Tags: arm

In  [1.4.1. Format summary](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0210c/Cacggfhh.html&_ga=2.10987191.284676948.1543457643-1784346721.1535783186) section of ARM7TDMI Technical Reference Manual, the Figure 1-5 show that the 25th bit of ARM7TDMI Data-processing instructions is always 1, but according to ARM Architecture Reference Manual, this bit represents whether the shifter operand is immediate and can be 0. This bit is I bit, because I looks like 1, I guess this may be a typo in ARM7TDMI Technical Reference Manual. Is it really a typo?

[image]

Comment: You mean  like 'Multiply', the 2nd line in that table?

Comment: @SeanHoulihane, I don't know whether "Data Processing" includes "Multiply", but for instructions like "add r1, r2, r3", their 25th bit is 0.

Comment: what rev of the manual do you have I see it corrected in mine.  there were many versions of the manual from the printed books through into pdf form.  I see two flavors of data processing one with 25 set and one with it reset.  one with detail on using an immediate the other for other forms...

Comment: Im looking at rev E which if I remember right matches the last printed book rev.  Rev I which I think is what you get off their website currently also shows the two forms with and without bit 25 set as data processing.

Comment: Im looking at the arm arm which contains the instruction set, the trm shows the instruction set?

Comment: yeah, thats a bug in that manual, looks like it hasnt been updated since 2004 where the arm arm's last updates were more recent (not that much).  Not a whole not of demand to need to fix it.  Just like chip bugs in older cores are not being documented anymore either...